# Google Apps Script Html Form Without Page Refresh

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, iframe, web-applications

Currently, I am changing an app that I had built for my organization from UiService to HtmlService. This part isn't the hard part.

However, in the past iteration of the app, submitting the form obviously creates a refresh(?) or at least an elimination of the form from visibility. This was one of the biggest complaints for this app in particular for users who need to put in multiple entries at a time.

For my other apps, it was as simple as replacing the submit button with an onClick function. However, because this app Requires an attachment, I haven't found a way to have the form submit without refreshing the page. I have tried returning false; and other methods proposed for normal HTML/JavaScript based pages.

Is this a limitation with Google Apps Script HtmlService because of the Caja Sanitation or the iframe Sandbox?

Comment: We need to see your code.  We need to see your button, your HTML, your `google.script.run.funcName()`

Answer (score 0):

So after doing some research, the answer was right under my nose. It was on Googles Best Practice for HtmlService.

Comment: What is the answer?